# SignalR constant stream of data?

Tags: c#, stream, signalr, opc-ua

I'm quite new to SignalR. I've setup a frontend in React that connects to a SignalR backend which itself connects to a machine via OPC-UA *(It's a school project)*

The purpose of the program is to *stream live data from a PLC to my React frontend*. The way I do it now is this: Connect via a button in frontend -> Frontend invokes a method that subscribes to some PLC nodes  which then sends the data back.

**My problem is that I need to keep the invoked method running with a 'while(true)' loop** otherwise I get an error because the Hub object is disposed.

(This makes the PLC call SubscriptionHandler when a node values changes, which gives an error cause the Hub object isnt there anymore *I think*) -> `(new OpcSubscribeDataChange("ns=6;s=::Program:Cube.Command.CntrlCmd", SubscriptionHandler)`

**How do I keep the connection alive in a proper way without the Hub object being disposed?**

This is the SignalR code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Opc.UaFx.Client;
using Connections;

namespace StreamBackend.Hubs
{
    public class DataHub : Hub
    {   
        private IHubContext<DataHub> _context;

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {   
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "ConnectedUsers");
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Client Connected");

            OPC.Client.Connect();

        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "SignalR");
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);

            Console.WriteLine("Removed: " + Context.ConnectionId);
        }

        public DataHub(IHubContext<DataHub> context) {
            _context = context;

            // Implement check on whether connected already or not
            Console.WriteLine("Constructor");
        }

        public async void SubscriptionHandler(object sender, OpcDataChangeReceivedEventArgs e) {
            OpcMonitoredItem item = (OpcMonitoredItem)sender;
            var NodeId = Convert.ToString(item.NodeId);
            var Value = Convert.ToString(e.Item.Value);
            await SendData(NodeId, Value);
        } 

        public async Task SendData(string NodeId, string Value) {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("LatestChange", NodeId, Value);
        }

        public async Task DataHubConnection()
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("InvokeMethodFromBackend");

             OpcSubscribeDataChange[] nodes = new OpcSubscribeDataChange[] {
                    new OpcSubscribeDataChange("ns=6;s=::Program:Cube.Command.CntrlCmd", SubscriptionHandler),
                    new OpcSubscribeDataChange("ns=6;s=::Program:Cube.Command.Parameter[0].Value", SubscriptionHandler)
                };

                OpcSubscription subscription = OPC.Client.SubscribeNodes(nodes);

                // This keeps the "Hub" alive. It is needed, cause it is the SubscriptionHandlers accesspoint
                while(true) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Open");
                     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); //Hang out for half a second (testing)
                    }
                } 
                // 1006 error is when the server closes the connection
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend Webhooks instead of signal R.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [SignalR-Handbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hub-object-lifetime), this is intended behavior:

> Hub object lifetime
>
> You don't instantiate the Hub class or call its methods from  your own code on the server; all that is done for you by the  SignalR Hubs pipeline. SignalR creates a new instance of   your Hub class each time it needs to handle a Hub operation  such as when a client connects, disconnects, or makes a method call to the server.
>
> Because instances of the Hub class are transient, you can't  use them to maintain state from one method call to the next.  Each time the server receives a method call from a client, a  new instance of your Hub class processes the message. To maintain state through multiple connections and method calls, use some other method such as a database, or a static variable on the Hub class, or a different class that does not derive from Hub. If you persist data in memory, using a method such as a static variable on the Hub class, the data will be lost when the app domain recycles.

You need to write a class, which have OPC Client and OPC subscriptions as members. The class should be inserted into the hub via DependencyInjection, see as example *IStockTicker* in [Dependency Injection in SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection)